# Как обратиться к файлу в jar`e

Tags: java, jar

Таких вопросов очень много. Сейчас полтора часа убил, все пересмотрел - нет ни одного, что бы помог мне. Есть в приложении Graphics gr, рисует изображение по File f. Если указывать путь к любому изображению на пк (например c://a.png), всё прекрасно работает. Но вот мне нужно этот самый a.png запихнуть в исполняемый jar файл, который ето изображение и должен вывести в своё окно. Пробовал: getClass().getClassLoader().getResourse("a.png") и совал файл в classpath. Нет, не работает, причём использовал самые разные комбинации: getClass.getRosourse() и getResourseAsStream, ничего не помогает. Как быть?

Comment: Вы сам файл _a.png_ в _.jar_ добавили или нет? Проверяли итоговый _.jar_ - в нём эта картинка есть?

Comment: да, тут всё норм. Файл имеется

Comment: А расположен в _.jar_-е он где? В корне? И почему у вас в вопросе слово "resource" везде неправильно написано?

Comment: .getResource, так? и в jar`e он в корне, да.

Comment: Подскажите, как в MANIFEST.MF должна выглядеть строка Class Path? у меня так:  Class Path: .

Comment: Если в корне, то попробуйте `getResourceAsStream("/a.png")`. А _Class-Path_ с картинками не связан.